# get value from an input with datedropper js in the onchange event

Tags: javascript, jquery, onchange, datedropper

I'm using the js library from `datedropper`, but when I want to get its value, when it changes value, no value returns, I don't know what is the correct way to do it

```
<input id="my-timepicker"type="text" data-lang='es' data-large-mode="true" data-large-default="true">




$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#my-timepicker").dateDropper();



    $("#my-timepicker").change(function () {
        console.log($(this).val());

    });

});
```

Comment: When you trying to use any plugin please read the documentation well .. There're a full list of callback [**Here**](https://felicegattuso.com/datedropper/doc/explore-the-full-list-of-datedropper-callbacks/) go to `onchange` section

Comment: I read the documentation and I don't understand how to use it, so I ask here

Comment: Never Mind  `$("#my-timepicker").dateDropper({ onchange : function(response){ console.log(response.date.Y) } });` .. `.Y` for year `.m` for month `.d` for day .. Note: I didn't use this plugin before but that's how it is in documentation

Comment: Also, Please when you asked about any plugin provide the link of this plugin because there're tons of plugins over the web even with same name .. hope the code help :-)